# check internet in android emulator

Tags: java, android, connectivity, internet-connection

i am trying to check internet connection in my android app

```
    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    Log.d("Network",
                            "NETWORKnAME: " + info[i].getTypeName());
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

but problem is that when i try to check internet connection in emulator by turning off host PC internet connection still this function returning true that is internet available while i have turn off internet connection from host PC
 `ConnectivityManager` class  help in determining whether connected with the network not about the internet connectivity

my question is how to check internet connection is not available ?

Comment: if you are using mac press f8 to turn off internet on emulator and try again

Comment: no i am using windows and genymotion emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try again after turning off wifi and data package..hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try this to detect your internet connection

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context mContext) {

            try {
                ConnectivityManager connect = null;
                connect = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                if (connect != null) {
                    NetworkInfo resultMobile = connect
                            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

                    NetworkInfo resultWifi = connect
                            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                    if ((resultMobile != null && resultMobile
                            .isConnectedOrConnecting())
                            || (resultWifi != null && resultWifi
                                    .isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Add the following permissions to your manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: can you see my Question i have check connection using `ConnectivityManager` that is not working thats why i have asked here and you are check only two type of connection in my question i have check all type of connection